# Objective-C / iOS Memory Management Questions

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I am interested in learning a bit more about the implementation and proper use of memory management in iOS, particularly Objective-C.

1. When you `-release` an object when does the memory actually get released and is available for use by something else?
2. How does ARC know where to insert / synthesise the various `-retain` and `-release` messages into the code during compilation (and does it happen during compilation, or some other time)?
3. I am a bit uncertain about the correct use and purpose of `autorelease`. For example, when writing a method which returns an array I usually `-alloc` and `-init` that array at the beginning of the function, and then `return` it at the end.

For example:

```
- (NSArray *)myMethod {

   NSMutableArray *theArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   // Do other stuff here

   return theArray;

}
```

Should I be `-autorelease`ing that array too? For example:

```
- (NSArray *)myMethod {

   NSMutableArray *theArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   // Do other stuff here

   return [theArray autorelease];

}
```

4. In what situations is it better to use a convenience constructor on an object (e.g. `[NSArray array]`) rather than `-alloc` and `-init` the object?
5. When creating a new object, and assigning it to a property which is `strong`, should I assign it to an intermediate variable rather than directly to the property, to avoid a double retain (once on the `-alloc` and `-init`, and then again on the assignment to the `strong` property)?

For example, should I do this:

```
NSMutableArray *theNewArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.newArray = theNewArray;
```

rather than this:

```
self.newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Thanks in advance for any help with these questions!

Comment: "I am interested in learning a bit more about the implementation and proper use of memory management in iOS" But not, it seems, interested enough to do any research?

Comment: Well, I've written a book that explains it all to you. There's not a thing you've asked that isn't answered in this chapter: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_memory_management

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The memory becomes available for others to use as soon as the object gets deallocated. The latter happens when its retain count reaches 0, that is, there's been a **release** for each time it has been **retained**.
2. There's a naming convention in Objective-C that any time you call a method that says "alloc", "copy" or "new" in its name you get to own the object that's been created and you have the responsibility to release it some time later. Additionally, when you call a method that starts with the name of the thing you want to receive back (i.e. a factory method such as [NSString stringWithFormat:], [NSDate date], etc), the object that's returned is always autoreleased, which means you don't have to worry about releasing it.

These naming rules became so important and well adhered to that, when ARC came around, Apple was able to build them in ARC itself. So, during compilation, ARC is inserting the releases, autoreleases and retains for you in the right places.

3. Autorelease marks an object to be released some time later (in the next run loop) instead of being released immediately as would happen with a regular release. The object gets added to an autorelease pool along with any others that have also been autoreleased. Before ARC you would use autorelease when you were returning from a method an object that you had ownership (i.e. created via alloc, copy or new). If just released it normally instead the object would likely get deallocated before it would be able to be used by the calling function. With ARC you don't have to worry about any of this stuff and can just return the object directly.
4. There are times that the factory times are more convenient. [NSString stringWithFormat:] lets you initialize an string passing placeholders. [NSDate date] gives you back the current date already initialized. If you alloc/init in these cases instead you'd have to have one or two extra lines of code to get the same results. Memory management in theses cases doesn't really matter at all anymore in theses cases in a world with ARC.
5. No need to worry about that. You can just assign it directly. The compiler will optimize the retains/releases.

Answer (score 0):

1. when you `release` an object its retain count is decremented. When its retain count reaches 0, it will be deallocated;
2. its primarily based on scope. When a pointer goes out of scope, it releases what it was pointing to if it held an owning reference;
3. `autorelease` (i) adds that object to the autorelease pool; and (ii) releases it. It therefore ends your ownership of the object but ensures its lifetime will last at least as long as the current pool. If you've got an owning reference (one from a new, alloc, retain or create), you should ensure you release it. If you need to release it but also return it, you should autorelease.
4. when you want a non-owning reference;
5. no. Unless you want to. There will be no double retain. The compiler isn't stupid.